# Is there a way to discover the specific HTTP requests my browser sends while I navigate?

Tags: http, curl, automation, httpwebrequest, http-headers

The question is pretty straightforward. I want to know if there are ways of discovering the HTTP requests my browser sends while I navigate. For instance, what happens when I click on a certain link which sends a PUT method? I mean, I wish I could determine the exact HTTP request that my browser sends to that website. Further, I want to, later, reproduce that request on Curl. Basically, I want to inspect requests my browser sends so I can automate that task later through the Curl command (command, not library).

Thanks in advance!

Fernando.

Comment: Firefox [Live HTTP headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) add-on?

Comment: Actually, this Live HTTP Headers add-on was the method which I most liked from those here. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 5):

Fiddler does exactly what you want.  It sets up a proxy that can monitor http communication from your browser.
http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: Seems a good tool. Unfortunately I was not able to test it because I use Mac OS X, but I managed to use other tools. thanks very much.

Answer (score 4):

You would want the Firebug extesion for Firefox. It can show a lot of what is happening, and you can add more options by installing more extensions.

On the other hand, you can use [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to capture the traffic to and from your computer.
Then you can use filters to save the relevant packets (pcap is often the format for storing the packets).
Later, you can replay the packets using tools like tcpreplay.

You could try it out with backtrack linux (live cd/usb).
And nowadays there should be some new tools for windows also. :)

Answer (score 1):

EO2 and JohnnyC are correct. Fiddler, WireShark, FireBug (FireFox addon), etc. are what you are going to look for. You can use them free of charge.

WireShark will capture all incoming and outgoing traffic on your box. You can listen on any port, filter data etc.

FireBug will capture outgoing and incoming data streams, the raw data (XML, JSON, images etc.) for each request.

Fiddler is great for tracking web data in a seperate application if you do not use FireFox.